# Why does my label not have any text in it? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following subroutine to create a label, located in form 1:

```
private void MakeLabelForGameStyle()
{
    Label SelectedMode = new Label();
    SelectedMode.Text = form2obj.GameStyle;
    SelectedMode.Location = new Point(507, 92);
    SelectedMode.AutoSize = true;
    SelectedMode.Font = new Font("Calibri", 12);

    Controls.Add(SelectedMode);
}
```

In form 2, the relevant code to determine 'GameStyle' is as follows:

```
private string gameStyle;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gameStyle = "Best Of 3";
    Close();
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gameStyle = "Best of 5";
    Close();
}
public string GameStyle
{
    get { return gameStyle; }
}
```

But when I run the program, the label is blank after clicking either of the buttons.

Comment: `the label is blank after clicking either of the buttons` - I assume you are clicking either of the buttons after creating the label?

Comment: `using (var f = new [Your form2obj]()) { if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { MakeLabelForGameStyle(f.GameStyle) } }`

Comment: @GSerg I am clicking the buttons, then creating the label, as form2 is run before form1.

Comment: @Jimi What do you mean by [Your form2obj]()

Comment: The Form Type you're using here: `SelectedMode.Text = form2obj.GameStyle;`

Comment: `SelectedMode.Text = form2obj.GameStyle;`  You haven't shown us how and when `form2obj` was created and stored.